# No internet on Arch, lspci is stuck

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux

I've installed the latest Arch on an Eluktronics N857EK1 laptop following the Arch wiki installation guide.

When I was still running on the live iso, the internet (using a wired connection) was working fine. After booting into the installed system, there was no internet, and when I tried following the network configuration manual on the Arch wiki, the command

```
lspci -v
```

cause my computer to freeze, and even after resetting (using Alt+Ctrl+Del), the computer was not able to terminate the session.

1. Could the issue be caused by the graphics driver (Nvidia)?
2. What other diagnostics can I run?
3. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues:

1) No networking - I had to run dhcpcd and it configured my network.

2) lspci issue - After installing the latest nvidia drivers, the problem was fixed.

Thanks to the help from the Arch linux IRC channel!